# Regex Pattern with two equal but unknown parts

Tags: php, regex

I am currently working on a simple template engine. In a template, if-statements can be used. An if block looks like this

```
{% name IF: a EQUALS b %}

content

{% name ENDIF %}
```

I want to identify these blocks via regex.
The Problem is I need a regex pattern which contains two unknown but equal parts.
This is the pattern which matches to all blocks:

```
/{% +(.*) +IF: +(.*) +%}([\s\S]*){% +(.*) +ENDIF +%}/gm
```

To clarify which ENDIF marker belongs to which IF the first and the last capture group needs to be the same.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
{%\s+(\S+)\s+IF:.+?%}(?s)(.+?){%\s+\1\s+ENDIF\s+%}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLCi5P/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `{%`: Match `{%`
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)`:
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `IF:`: Match `IF:`
- `.+?`: Match 1+ of any character (non-greedy)
- `%}`: Match `%}`
- `(?s)`: Enable DOTALL mode so that dot matches line break
- `(.+?)`: 1st capture group to match 1+ of any characters
- `{%`: Match `{%`
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `\1`: Match same value as what we captured in capture group #1
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `ENDIF`: Match `ENDIF`
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `%}`: Match closing `%}`

Comment: This does not match the block of text I gave in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Cary, I have taken care of that. It wasn't clear from question if a standalone `%` is allowed within `IF` condition block.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the following regular expression (with general `g`, multiline `m` and case-indifferent `i` flags set).

```
{% +([a-z]+) +IF:.*? +%}\r?\n(?:^.*\r?\n)*?{% +\1 +ENDIF +%}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ULCJyS/1)

The expression breaks down as follows (alternatively, hover the cursor of each element of the expression at the regex101.com link to obtain an explanation of its function).

```
{% +             # match `{%` followed by one or more spaces
([a-z]+) +       # match one or more letters followed by one or more spaces
IF:.*? +%}\r?\n  # match 'IF: followed by zero or more characters, matched
                 # lazily, followed by one or more spaces followed by '%}'
                 # followed by a line terminator (`\r?` to satisfy Windows)
(?:              # begin non-capture group
  ^              # match beginning of line
  .*\r?\n        # match one or more characters other than newlines followed
                 # by a line terminator
)*?              # end non-capture group and execute it zero or more times, lazily
{% +             # match `{%` followed by one or more spaces
\1 +             # match the content of capture group 1 followed by one or
                 # more spaces
ENDIF +          # match `ENDIF` followed by one or more spaces
%}$              # match `{%` at the end of a line
```

The link demonstates that if the block of text were:

```
{% Saffi IF: my { % dog } has fleas %}

content

{% Saffi ENDIF %}
```

it too would be matched.

Comment: Still fleas? :-) You could shorten `\r?\n` to `\R` and perhaps match horizontal whitespace chars `\h+` instead of a mere space.

Comment: @The, she's not infested; she only keeps some as pets. Thanks for the tips.